# Deploying CRM Analytics Components to Scratch Org Fails

Tags: scratch-org, analytics, crm

We have developed CRM Analytics components in a developer org on which SF Support enabled CRM Analytics licenses for us.  The long term goal is to package these components and the first step is to be able to automate the deploy of these components to scratch orgs.  We want to automate the setup of scratch orgs both for development and for our CI processes.  When we deploy with the sf cli, we get this error on every component: "Not available for deploy for this organization".

I guessed some feature(s) need to be enabled, I experimented with adding these features to the project-scratch-def.json file:

1. AnalyticsAppEmbedded
2. AnalyticsAdminPerms

I still get the same error.  Is there anyone out here who has used scratch orgs for developing packages with CRM analytics who can share how to automate the setup of scratch orgs with analytics components deployed.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we enable Einstein Analytics in salesforce org? Do we need to purchase license?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294939/how-can-we-enable-einstein-analytics-in-salesforce-org-do-we-need-to-purchase-l)

Answer (score 0):

David Reed answered this question well [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294939/how-can-we-enable-einstein-analytics-in-salesforce-org-do-we-need-to-purchase-l).

Finding the correct [Features](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) & [Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_settings.htm) can be confusing because of how many times this product has been re-named (**CRM Analytics** <-- Tableau CRM <-- Einstein Analytics <-- Wave ...)